# How to Increase the Number of Characters in a MSSQL Table Column Using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, varchar, alter

Currently, I have a table column that has a text limit of 255 (Varchar[255]), I would like the number of characters increased to 4000 or more. What would the code be, if ran through a PHP page, to make this modification?

Note* - I have modified a column with a `varchar(100)` to `varchar(255)`, it seems that my columns cannot exceed a `varchar` of `255`.

So far I have used this - alas, it doesn't work:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 's036';
$dbuser = 'rost';
$dbpass = 'rosword';
 $conn=mssql_connect('smtscom','sTrsr','Rsa');
mssql_select_db('Gsa',$conn);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
$sql = "ALTER TABLE new_tders2 ALTER 

COLUMN description varchar(4000)";

mssql_select_db('Gsa');
$retval = mssql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not create table:');
}
echo "Table column modified successfully\n";
mssql_close($conn);
?>
```

When I run the PHP page (the code above), it says "Table column modified successfully", but I still can only input 255 characters into the column.

Comment: The code is crazy. why are you selecting the `d` database at the start, then switching to `Gsa` later on? you're also checking for successful connection **AFTER** you've already tried to use the db.

Comment: I changed the name of the database, dbhost, password, etc. from the actual code itself in order to maintain my privacy. However, I am looking for the `$sql` part of the code, as mine doesn't seem to work.

Comment: well, then hopefully your user/pass aren't `sTrsr` and `Rsa`, because your dbhost/dbuser/dbpass variables never get used in the code.

Comment: They aren't. The connection is fine in the actual code, hence why it says `"Table column modified successfully"` when I run the page.

Comment: well, that's all fine and dandy, but you've got two DBs being used in the code. perhaps you have the same table in both DBs and are modifying it one, and then using the unmodified other copy. In other words, there's nothing "really wrong" with your code above, and you should be investigating elsewhere.

Comment: The database name is not `Gsa`, nor `d`. I only modified the name in the question so others wouldn't try to steal my personal information. Nevertheless, I have changed the `d` to `Gsa` in my question. Hopefully, that will make the code more "clear" to you.

Comment: Do the user have permission to alter the table?

Comment: I can update tables, add new tables, and even delete table rows, so I don't think I do not have permission to alter them.

Comment: Why are issuing ddl statements from a web page??? Also in your question you said you wanted to increase to 4000 but in your code it is varchar(max). Something seems very wrong when you start doing alter table statements from a web page. You might also at the very least add some checks about the current state of the column and not bother trying to alter it to the same thing.

Comment: How do I add checks about the current state of the column? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - instead of using `VARCHAR(4000)`, use `TEXT`. It will exceed `4000` characters, and allow up to 64 Kb, 2 bytes overhead. However, this is fine in my case, as more than 4000 characters is fine for this part of the website.

Here is the new (working) code:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 's036';
$dbuser = 'rost';
$dbpass = 'rosword';
 $conn=mssql_connect('smtscom','sTrsr','Rsa');
mssql_select_db('Gsa',$conn);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
$sql = "ALTER TABLE new_tders2 ALTER 

COLUMN description TEXT";

mssql_select_db('Gsa');
$retval = mssql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not create table:');
}
echo "Table column modified successfully\n";
mssql_close($conn);
?>
```

Thank you to all those that tried to answer.

Comment: Don't use text as a datatype. It is deprecated and is a serious pain to work with. If you really need more than 4000 characters use varchar(max).

Comment: Varchar(max) is the same as Varchar(255) for me.

Comment: HUH? varchar(255) is NOT the same thing as varchar(max). varchar(255) holds up to 255 characters, where varchar(max) will hold up to 2GB. Again, the text datatype is deprecated and will be removed in the future. The only way you can search is with fulltext indexing or casting it to varchar(max). Can you explain why you think that varchar(255) is the same as varchar(max)?

Comment: Because I tried varchar(max) and the column would only store 255 characters. Mind you, I am using MSSQL, not MySQL.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. There must be something with your code because varchar(max) will hold 2gb of text and fully indexable, unlike the text datatype. I assumed it was sql server since that is what is tagged. I don't know squat about mysql. :)